# Projection measures and integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $(M, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ a probability space, $Y$ compact metric space.

Consider $\mathcal{M}(\mu)$ be the space of probability measures $\eta$ on $M\times Y$ such that $\pi_{*}\eta=\mu $ where $\pi: M\times Y \rightarrow M$ is the canonical projection.

Let $\phi : M\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int \sup_{y\in Y}\vert \phi(x,y)\vert d\mu$ is finite.

I wonder if the following statement is true: For all $\eta \in \mathcal{M}(\mu)$ then $\phi \in L^1(\mu\times \eta)$ ?

I think if by the following:

$ \vert \int\phi(x,y) d\eta\vert\leq \int \sup_{y\in Y}\vert \phi(x,y)\vert d\eta= \int f\circ\pi(x,v) d\eta(x,v)= \int f(x) d\mu< \infty$

where $f(x)=\sup_{y\in Y}\vert \phi(x,y)\vert$

since

$\int f\circ\pi(x,v) d\eta(x,v)=\int f d\pi_{*}\eta= \int f(x) d\mu$.

Grateful tell me if my reasoning is correct